# Nested iterators - batch merge from multiple outputs

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, merge, batch, iterator

I'd like to ask you some advice for nesting an iterator (from a submodel) into a master model which also include an iterator (see pic attached). The whole purpose is to 'Merge' the iteration output of the submodel with an iterated file from the master model.
The tricky part is where both iteration have to occur successively and assemble the right iterated features at the right timing before the 'Merge' operation.

Any experience in this?

[image]

Comment: Is your intention to collect all the layers in you sub-model and merge those with each layer coming out of the iterator in the master model? If the sub-model workspace is spitting out 3 layers and your master model workspace is spitting out 4 layers then you are hoping to get 4 new layers combined from 4 layers (3 sub & 1 master)? If not you need to edit your question and explain a bit more.

Comment: @Hornbydd #thumbsup for understanding something here :)

Comment: Hi @Hornbydd, in the submodel, there is only one shapefile that needs to be called at a time from a multi-shapefile folder. This layer then needs to be merged to a shapefile called from another multi-shapefile in the master model. Hence both iterators. In the end, only one layer at each iteration is produced by the 'Merge' operation.

Comment: I believe what you are trying to achieve cannot be done with modelbuilder as an iterator causes everything in the model to execute _X_ number of times _then_ exit the sub-model. You cannot jump in and out of the sub-model. Have a look at the explanation on this [page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002w0000007p000000). The logic you are looking for can be done with a fairly simple python script.